# Majuscule après la formule d'appel dans une lettre

Tags: typographie, salutations, correspondance, majuscules

Voici une introduction d'une lettre trouvée sur Internet:

> Chère Madame la Maire,
>
> Je vous écris en tant que responsable de la ligue de protection des animaux pour demander l’interdiction de la tauromachie dans...

Je me demande toujours pourquoi il faut écrire la première lettre de la phrase après la salutation avec une majuscule puisqu'elle suit une virgule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est une très bonne question qui trouve une réponse facile :

Il ne s'agit que de *typographie*. Et, en matière de typographie, il n'est que des usages.

Usage venu de l'habitude de commencer par une lettre capitale une ligne de texte écrite après un passage à la ligne + saut de ligne. (cf poésies)

On notera un fait curieux, Grevisse, grand observateur des usages de la langue va noter, dans sa 13e édition (§ 97, 2°) *"on **doit** mettre une majuscule à cette lettre initiale, malgré la virgule qui la précède."* Il était moins catégorique dans sa 12e édition qui fait disparaître ce *doit* : *"on met la majuscule à cette lettre initiale"*...

aMuSAnt noN ?

On notera qu'il en va de même dans les livres lorsque les titres de chapitre commencent une phrase qui va se poursuivre ensuite à la ligne. Beaucoup d'auteurs / éditeurs commenceront la suite par un retrait et une majuscule. Mais... certains (cf Le Clézio / Gallimard) débuteront la suite avec une minuscule sans retrait.

Pour ce qui me concerne, je crois la casse de cette première lettre du texte après l'appel lié au retrait de première ligne. Tu fais un retrait de première ligne => Capitale. Tu n'en fais pas -> bas de casse.

Comment: Merci. Pourquoi ce doit a disparaît ? C'est bizarre comme tu constates. Poser une question sur une virgule c'est plus simple que demander s'il faut dire **Chère Madame la Maire** ou **Chère Madame le Maire** :-)!

Comment: *Doit* disparait car il n'est en la matière nulle question d'obliger à une règle. On ne fait que constater un usage répandu genre : *Tu fais ce que tu veux, je te dis juste comment (à tort ou à raison) on (c'est à dire tout monde) fait.*

Answer (score 1):

Le terme « salutation » ne convient pas; je ne connais pas le terme à utiliser mais voyez ceci : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/salutation

Terme suggéré (pas nécessairement le terme consacré) : formule d'entrée

La virgule est le résultat seulement d'une coutume uniquement utilisée dans les lettres ou messages écrits, et cela n'a rien à voir avec des principes de grammaire; la logique de la chose est, comme n'importe qui peut le concevoir aisément, que tout ce qui vient en dessous de l'« entrée » (ce qui est appelé « salutation » dans la question) est adressé à la personne nommée; elle permet un simili sur papier de l'acte de s'adresser à quelqu'un de vive voix puisqu'elle indique une légère pause, on pourrait dire même qu'elle permet de le représenter. La première phrase qui suit n'est pas la seule qui soit à l'intention de la personne et les autres phrases devront commencer par une majuscule; il n'y a donc pas de raison de singulariser la première et par cela rendre l'interprétation ambigüe; une majuscule est donc le choix le plus « sain ».

Comment: *appel*. Il s'agit de ce que l'on appelle... un *appel*. ;-)

Comment: Merci pour la réponse exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une convention qui fait exception à la règle habituelle.

La **formule d'appel** est considérée comme une partie indépendante, même si elle se termine par une virgule.

Comment: 1+. Malheureusement je ne peux pas choisir toutes ces bonnes réponses. Merci encore !